# if a database contains a certain value add x amount to a variable (python)

Tags: python, database, ms-access, multiple-columns, pull

I have a ton of variables but lets just say i have one, i am trying to make it so i have an if statement that says if it runs across a certain number in the database take the variable value and add one to it.  I have been researching for a little bit now and haven't found any thing i think is valuable.  Does anyone know if you can do this in python if so can you please help?

thank you.

I am thinking it might need to be a for loop because it is a repeating process but i do not know.

Comment: Does this value will be in particulr column or irrespective of any column? So, if you are searching for a value = 12345, it searches the whole DB as in all the columns and all the rows and just add 1 and make it 12346?

Comment: No I’m starting with a variable (x) and it equals 0 to start off with.  I am trying to scan certain columns for a certain number and every time it finds that number it does x= x + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=['a', 'b']) ## Sample DF

df.loc[df['b'] == 4, 'b'] = [9]  ## b is desired column, "4" is a value you are searching and 9 is the new value
```

OR To update multiple columns on 1 condition

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1], [1,4]], columns=['a', 'b'])

df.loc[df['b'] == 1, ['a','b']] = [9]
```

Or if you want to increment a column with certain number you can do folllowing for one or more columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3, (5, 3)), columns=list('abc'))
ids=[0,2]
df.loc[df.a.isin(ids), ['b','c']] += 1
```

OR : To increment a variable:

```
## name of the variable count
count = 6
if count ==6:
    count+=1
```

Comment: what if i want multiple desired columns

Comment: and would the nine be changing the number currently in the database?

Comment: because i just want to add to a variable that has nothing to do with the database.

Comment: what if i want to increment a variable?

Comment: and not a column

Comment: Updated the aswer